# Prove the normal will be at constant distance form origin in this parametric function?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

Given a function,

$x = a(cos \theta + \theta \sin\theta])$, $y = a(sin\theta - \theta\ cos\theta)$, $a \in R$

Prove that the normal drawn on each point is at constant distance form the origin?
If possible?
I tried to plot it but found that it is not the case?

Comment: don't you usually define **unit** tangent/normal vectors to curves? Or how do you define "normal to"

Comment: DonAntonio the normals to tangent to points on the curve!indeed

Comment: Well, that didn't answer my question: what is **your** definition??

Comment: this can be done without vectors also using 2-D simple geometry! @DonAntonio

Comment: Again, that last comment of yours does not address my first question, @Ideed...and yet, assuming you mean the *usual* stuff (say, from differential geometry), I already posted an answer. And it can't be "2-D simple geometry": as far as I can see, you *need* differential calculus, at least.

Answer (score 1):

$$r(t):=\left(a(\cos t+t\sin t)\,,\,a(\sin t-t\cos t)\right)\implies$$

$$T(t):=r'(t)=(at\cos t\,,\,at\sin t)\implies \frac{T(t)}{||T(t)||}=(\cos t, \sin t)$$

$$T'(t)=(a\cos t-at\sin t\,,\,a\sin t+at\cos t)\implies $$

$$\implies N(t):=\frac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)}||=\left(\frac{\cos t}{a(1+t^2)}-\frac{t\sin t}{a(1+t^2)}\;,\;\frac{\sin t}{a(1+t^2)}+\frac{t\cos t}{a(1+t^2)}\right)$$

and now check that $\;||N(t)||\;$ doesn't depend on $\;t\;$ ...

Comment: This is not what is meant by the problem: at each point of the curve, draw the line tangent to the curve, now the perpendicular to that through that point, and measure the distance from that last line to the origin.